# How to increase the vertical movement tolerance of horizontal UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I implemented a horizontal UIScrollView with few different sections for individual page and each sections are implemented as UITableView to be scrolled vertically.

How to increase the vertical movement tolerance of horizontal UISwipeGestureRecognizer to make the horizontal swiping easier? 
Currently the horizontal swipe has almost no vertical movement tolerance since vertical movement will be interpreted as scrolling the UITableView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling paging yourself with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, just set `pagingEnabled=YES` on your horizontal UIScrollView.

This will provide more fluid results as well as working around the specific problem you describe.